# OpenGL: 2D Vertex coordinates to 2D viewing coordinates?

Tags: opengl, graphics, transform, glut

I'm implementing a rasterizer for a class project, and currently im stuck on what method/how i should convert vertex coordinates to viewing pane coordinates.

I'm given a list of verticies of 2d coordinates for a triangle, like

```
 0 0 1  
 2 0 1  
 0 1 1
```

and im drawing in a viewing pane (using OpenGL and GLUT) of size 400X400 pixels, for example.

My question is how do i decide where in the viewing pane to put these verticies, **assuming**

1) I want the coordinate's to be centered around 0,0 at the center of the screen
2) I want to fill up most of the screen (lets say for this example, the screen is the maximum x coordinate + 1 lengths wide, etc)
3) I have any and all of OpenGL's and GLUT's standard library functions at my disposal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml

To center around 0 use symmetric left/right and bottom/top.  Beware the near/far which are somewhat arbitrary but are often chosen (in examples) as -1..+1 which might be a problem for your triangles at z=1.

If you care about the aspect ratio make sure that right-left and bottom-top are proportional to the window's width/height.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the frustum which is your volumetric view and calculate the coordinates by transforming the  your objects to consider their position, [this](http://www.euclideanspace.com/threed/rendering/opengl/index.htm) explains the theory quite thoroughly..

basically you have to project the object using a specified projection matrix that is calculated basing on the characteristics of your view:

- scale them according to a z (depth) value: you scale both y and x in so inversely proportionally to z
- you scale and shift coordinates in order to fit the width of your view